# Difference between "Piccolo" and "Basso"

Tags: difference

What is the difference between `Piccolo` and `Basso`? They both mean `Small`, right??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Basso* is not only *short*, and *piccolo* is not only *small in size*!

*Piccolo*, as laika remarked, can also mean "[very] young" when referred to a person. *Basso* can be used to refer to a small amount of money ("una cifra *bassa*", "uno stipendio *basso*"). We say *basse aspettative* ("low expectations"), while *piccole aspettative* sounds awkward. We say *un piccolo problema* ("a small problem") while *un problema basso* is absurd. Quantity can be *piccola* ("small quantity"), whereas quality can be *bassa* ("low quality").

Talking about sound, *basso* can mean "low-pitched" but also "low in volume". Basically, when you are not talking about people, *basso* translates to "low" in most cases, not "short", and it is not always about height...

Fun fact: *Basso Medioevo* means "Late Middle Ages"!

It's not that simple, and you should address each case individually depending on the domain.

Comment: I am not quite sure, I am just quoting from the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

Basso means small in height (so short) and piccolo small in size.

Comment: piccolo can also be "little" regarding age